# how to get the min and max of two columns and concat the two value in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I want to sorted two columns inn MySQL and concat it as a new columns, but I did not know how to write the sql, I think the sql may look like this:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name 
ADD COLUMN pair_flag varchar
GENERATED ALWAYS AS (concat(min(col1,col2) , max(col,col2))) STORED;
```

how to write this logic the right way?

Comment: This is absolutely impossible - the expression of the generated column value may refer to current row columns values and deterministic scalar functions only. You may use a trigger (but the values won't be recalculated when the data array changes) or a view.

Comment: `MIN()` works over _rows_ in one column; `LEAST()` finds the smallest values amongst the arguments.